# filtering files by number in bash error unary operator expected

Tags: bash, filtering, unary-operator

I have a script that will find the distances between two atoms in pdb.

bash does not recognize decimals so I have put printf script to round the decimals.

and echo $b works fine and gives me a integer value.

but the if line for my filtering system does not work.

I get and error stating

```
 [: -ge: unary operator expected
```

below is part of the script that I am working on.

```
 a=$(awk '$2=='91'{x1=$6;y1=$7;z1=$8} $2=='180' {x2=$6;y2=$7;z2=$8} END{print sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2) + (z1-z2)*(z1-z2))}' ${names}.pdb.$i)
b= printf %.0f $a
echo $b
if [ $b -ge 1 ] &&[ $b -le 9 ]; then
```

any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you  in advanced.

Comment: Try instead `b=$(printf "%.0f" $a)`

Comment: Seems I answered your previous question, and it is fine. But you didn't accept it first.

Comment: @BMW Thx to you too. I found what I was doing worng.

Comment: In fact, you can do it all in awk. Awk has printf as well. Take a look on http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf.html#Printf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b= printf %.0f $a
```

This line sets the value of `b` to nothing for the duration of the printf command, which sends its output to stdout

```
echo $b
```

This prints a blank line.

You must not put whitespace around the `=` in an assignment, and to store the output of a command into a variable, you use this syntax:

```
b=$( printf %.0f $a )
```

You're getting the error because `$b` is empty, and this is what bash sees:

```
if [  -ge 1 ] &&[  -le 9 ]; then
```

`-ge` is expecting operands on both the left and the right, and it doesn't see one.

With bash, you should (almost) always prefer `[[ ... ]]` over `[ ... ]` -- the double bracket form is not fooled by variables containing empty strings.

You should always quote your `"$variables"` -- unless you know exactly when to not quote them.